# Pymongo returns none after successful update/remove operations

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The pymongo [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) says:

> By default an acknowledgment is requested from the server that the
>   update was successful, raising `OperationFailure` if an error occurred.

I am using Pymongo 2.7.1 with Python 2.7.5. Following operation returns `None`, whether the operation is successful or not:

```
user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$pull': {'friend_list': existing_friend}})
user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$pull': {'friend_list': non_existing_friend}})
```

In second statement I am trying to pull a something which does not exist in `friend_list`.

Same happens with `remove` also. It's also returns None, be the operation is successful or unsuccessful i.e. if it removed the document or not:

```
user_db.remove({'name': 'john'}
```

I passed `w=1` and I receive following response:

> {u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'connectionId': 12037, u'n': 1,
>   u'updatedExisting': True, u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403099751, 1)}

when I manually check the DB, I see it has pulled the name from `friend_list`. Now if I run same again i.e. trying to pull a name which does not exist in `friend_list`:

> {u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'connectionId': 12037, u'n': 1,
>   u'updatedExisting': True, u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403099873, 1)}

It is same as earlier.

So how do I know whether the update and delete operations are successful or not?

**EDIT**: As answers pointed out, I was using connection instead of MongoClient. Now I have updated, `remove` is working. However `update` is not working properly:

```
>>> conn = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGOHQ_URL)
>>> db = conn['test']
>>> test_collection = db.test
>>>
>>> test_collection.insert({'name': 'john'})
ObjectId('53a25612a760360253920619')
>>>  
>>> test_collection.update({'name': 'john'}, {'$addToSet': {'friends': 'merry'}})
{u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'connectionId': 12317, u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': True, u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403147936, 1)}
>>> 
>>> test_collection.update({'name': 'john'}, {'$pull': {'friends': 'merry'}})
{u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'connectionId': 12317, u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': True, u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403147959, 1)}
>>> 
>>> test_collection.update({'name': 'john'}, {'$pull': {'friends': 'merry'}})
{u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'connectionId': 12317, u'n': 1, u'updatedExisting': True, u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403147963, 1)}
>>>
```

The last statement is trying to remove an item from a list, even though the item no longer exists in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the terms. The section of the documentation you highlighted is referring to the write acknowledgement not number of documents that were updated.

In short, when driver sends a write command to MongoDB and you have the the default write acknowledgment (`w=1`) the driver will throw an `OperationFailure` error if MongoDB doesn't confirm that the updated completed successful. You can read more details about it on the [MongoDB pages](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#acknowledged).

Both of your updates were actually successful (MongoDB confirmed that the update was applied). That's why you didn't get an error. Your problem is that your update query didn't actually update any documents.

If you do that update in a MongoDB shell v2.6+, where no document are actually modified, you will get a result like this:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

And the result for an update that actually changed a document will look like this:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

**Edit:**

I was using the older version of pymongo (2.6.3) installed on Ubuntu with `apt-get` and I was getting the same response for the update query as you were getting.

I removed the python-pymongo package and updated to newest version of pymongo using `pip`. I got the following response from update that modified a document:

```
{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}
```

I tested this on MongoDB 2.6. using this code.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

m = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

db = m.test

print db.test.update({}, {'$pull': {'a'  : 1}})
```

**Edit2**

That's because you're using MongoDB 2.4. If you're using sandbox/free versions on MongoHQ you can't currently change that ([link](http://support.mongohq.com/getting-started/mongodb-version.html)).

MongoDB 2.6 is returning `updatedExisting` field in the response to the update command (which is one that's important to you). I suspect that's because the changed write protocol in v 2.6:

> A new protocol for write operations integrates write concerns with the
>   write operations, eliminating the need for a separate getLastError
>   command. Write methods now return the status of the write operation,
>   including error information.

Comment: But what does `n` and `ok` mean in this: `{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}`?

Comment: @SaadRehmanShah `ok: 1` means that the operation completed without errors and `n: 1` reports the number of documents matched by the update operation

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `pymongo.Connection`, which does unacknowledged writes to MongoDB by default. Therefore Connection doesn't tell you the outcome of your update operation.

Connection is deprecated; you should use `pymongo.MongoClient` instead. MongoClient has many advantages, including that it does acknowledged writes by default. If you use MongoClient you'll get information about each update:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> collection = pymongo.MongoClient().test.collection
>>> collection.insert({'_id': 1, 'array': ['a']})
1
>>> collection.update({'_id': 1}, {'$pull': {'array': 'a'}})
{u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1, 'updatedExisting': True, u'electionId': ObjectId('53a1a6bd30492fdb9fb5610a'), u'lastOp': Timestamp(1403111261, 1)}
```

Comment: ^I have updated the question. If you do another `pull` on the same document, the response is same.